# Unable to cast object of type WhereListIterator<system.web.Mvc.ListItem> to type system.web.mvc.listitem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a SelectList that I first check for a selected value != null and then want to use this selectedvalue in a where clause for a filter. Like so:

```
if(searchBag.Qualities.SelectedValue != null){
    ListItem selected = (ListItem)searchBag.Qualities.SelectedValue;
}
```

I made the cast in a seperate useless line to pinpoint the problem.
This gives me a

> Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[System.Web.Mvc.ListItem]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.ListItem'.

Weuh?

**--EDIT--**
It was indeed because multiple selections were made.
This was because on creation I set the selected value to theItems.Where(i=>i.someCriterea) and I forgot to put .FirstOrDefault() at the end. Ending up in the possibility of multiple answers.
Since it was an IEnumerable, it was a lazy list and hence the WhereListIterator I guess.
I solved it by simple putting FirstOrDefault at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already been explained, but here's another suggestion as to how to get what you're looking for:

```
if(searchBag.Qualities.SelectedValue != null){
    ListItem selected = (ListItem)searchBag.Qualities.SelectedValue.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the SelectList lets you select more than 1 item?

So SelectedValue is probably a list? Not 1 listitem.

Cast it to:

```
 WhereListIterator<ListItem> selected = (WhereListIterator<ListItem>)searchBag.Qualities.SelectedValue;
```

instead
and see what properties you have there.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedValue is not a ListItem, it's the value of the selected list item.  So given this:

```
var selectList = new SelectList(companiesList, "Id", "Name", companiesList[3]);
```

selectList.SelectedValue will equal companiesList[3].Id.  If you want the actual list item you can do something like this:

```
ListItem selected = selectList.GetListItems().Where(x => x.Value == selectList.SelectedValue.ToString())
```

Just curious, why do you want the selected list item?